# INMO 2021 polynomial question: Cubics with integer roots.

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

The question is the following:

> Find all pairs of integers $(a, b)$ so that each of the two cubic polynomials $x^3 +ax+b$ and $x^3 +bx+a$ has all the roots to be integers.

Only $a=b=0$ is possible. It turns out that the sum of squares of roots is an even integer and this leads to infinite descent.

Can you tell me other methods to solve this problem?

Comment: What are "all the roots" of $x^3-1$?

Comment: the cube roots of unity?

Comment: If you were working with real numbers (otherwise you may need to redefine an integer) then $1$ might be seen as the only root of $x^3-1$ and so all of them.

Comment: @Isomorphism What Henry is referring to is perceived ambiguity in the question statement. Are you only considering integer(s) among the real root(s)? Using that interpretation, $x^3-1$ has its single real root as an integer. Or do you require all three (not necessarily distinct) roots to be integers? Using that interpretation, $x^3-1$ has only one of its three roots as an integer. If the latter is what was meant, then, for precision, the question should be phrased "has three (not necessarily distinct) real roots, all of which are integers".

Comment: I copied the problem as it is from INMO 2021 document. I guess its generally assumed that polynomials are factored over complex numbers unless otherwise stated (in Indian olympiad literature).

Comment: It looks like a lot can be obtained using [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). The sum of the roots would have to be $0$ in both cases. Then the product of the 1st would have to be $b$ and the second $a$.

Comment: What about having a look at https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2478236p20786983

Answer (score 1):

Let $x^3+ax+b=(x-u)(x-v)(x+u+v)$ with $u,v>0$, otherwise change some signs. Then
$$ a= -(u+v)^2+uv \Rightarrow |a|<(u+v)^2.$$
For the case $u,v\geq 2$ we get
$$ b=uv(u+v)\geq(u+v)^2$$
and in total $|a|<|b|$. It remains to show, that the case $u=1$ isn't possible.

Comment: Why can you assume that 2 of the roots are positive? In fact, I believe that if a solution exists, we must have $a, b<0$ (which you have shown), and thus that 2 of the roots are negative. $\quad$ Can you flesh our your solution a bit more? It's not too clear to me what you're going for here.

Comment: @CalvinLin I tried for $|a|<|b|$, assuming $a,b\neq 0$. Replacing $x$ by $-x$ swaps the sign of all roots. Here I didn't check / use $a,b<0$. This could be useful for the remaining case u=-1, then. I'll rework the solution, but not today.